# How to use RadioGroup in ListView custom adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button

I want to show a single select option in my list. I am using `RadioButton` in my `listView` row. I know that `RadioGroup` is used for single selection.

But problem is that I have added the `RadioButton` in my `ListRowView`. Now I want to add all my list items in one `RadioButton`. I am using `Custom Adapter` and in `getView()`. I get the `RadioButton` in `getView()`, but when want to add it in `RadioGroup` it say

> "view already have parent , call removeView() in parent before"

And I know its true, but if I remove it from the view. Then it is not visible.

I also try to create and add `RadioButton` programmatically. And then add it in `RadioGrop`. And then to view of list row. But this time as the parent is `RadioGroup`, so again it say

> "view already have parent , call removeView() in parent before"

What I want to do is to select only one item in list at a time. My code is as follows.

#### getView

```
 public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter < MyMenuItem > {
    
    private LayoutInflater mInflater ;
    
    int                    mResource ;
    List < MyMenuItem >    mData ;
    Context context;
    
    public MyAdapter ( Context context , int resource , int textViewResourceId , List < MyMenuItem > data ) {
        super ( context , resource , textViewResourceId , data ) ;
        this.context = context;
        mData = data ;
        mResource = resource ;
        mInflater = ( LayoutInflater ) getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ) ;
    }
    
    @ Override
    public View getView ( int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent ) {
        ViewHolder holder = null ;
        if ( convertView == null ) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate ( mResource , null ) ;
            holder = new ViewHolder ( ) ;
            holder.icon = ( ImageView ) convertView.findViewById ( R.id.icon ) ;
            holder.text = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById ( R.id.text ) ;
            holder.comment = ( TextView ) convertView.findViewById ( R.id.comment ) ;
            LinearLayout lin = ( LinearLayout ) convertView.findViewById ( R.id.linerList ) ;
            RadioButton rbtn = new RadioButton ( context );
            LayoutParams lparam = new LayoutParams ( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
            rbtn.setSelected ( false );
            holder.check = rbtn;
            //radioGroup.addView ( rbtn );
            lin.addView ( rbtn , 0 );
            
            convertView.setTag ( holder ) ;
        } else {
            holder = ( ViewHolder ) convertView.getTag ( ) ;
        }
        
        holder.text.setText ( mData.get ( position ).getText ( ) ) ;
        holder.comment.setText ( mData.get ( position ).getComment ( ) ) ;
        
        holder.icon.setImageResource ( getApplicationContext ( ).getResources ( ).getIdentifier ( mData.get ( position ).getIcon ( ) ,
                "drawable" , getPackageName ( ) )

        ) ;
        
        return convertView ;
    }
    
}
```

My XML for the row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip">
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/linerList"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="My Application"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use RelativeLayout"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/light_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: It look like this if I not use RadioGroup]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Use `mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`
2. Make your custom row view implement `Checkable`. (More info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5612600/119895)).

Comment: So there is not way to use Radio Group. But to write custom view for such a case. I was expecting the same. Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @Arslan: Yep, in your case you just need to extend `LinearLayout`, implement the `Checkable` interface and those methods will return your `RadioButton` implementation.

Comment: Is there somewhere I can find a complete example of how to have radio button in custom adaptor and always only have one checked? I have searched very hard.

Answer (score 38):

This solution works and it's pretty clean, but there might be some better solutions out there.

You should use your adapter to manage the radio buttons state.

You must keep a reference to the last checked radio button, and then upon `RadioButton.onClick` you set the last checked radio button `setChecked(false)`.

also remember to set the newly selected radio button as the last selected radio button.

see example:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private int mResourceId = 0;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater; 
    private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
    private int mSelectedPosition = -1;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mResourceId = resource;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(view == null){

            view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.radioBtn = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }


        holder.radioBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(position != mSelectedPosition && mSelectedRB != null){
                    mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
                }

                mSelectedPosition = position;
                mSelectedRB = (RadioButton)v;
            }
        });


        if(mSelectedPosition != position){
            holder.radioBtn.setChecked(false);
        }else{
            holder.radioBtn.setChecked(true);
            if(mSelectedRB != null && holder.radioBtn != mSelectedRB){
                mSelectedRB = holder.radioBtn;
            }
        }




        holder.name.setText(getItem(position));


        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView        name;
        RadioButton     radioBtn;
    }
}
```

Hope it does it for you.

Comment: @inistel It's working, but I have a "confirmation page" that shows the selected radio and have the option to return to the previous page. The problem is, when I select again another radio it's not working anymore. There are already two chosen radios.

Comment: this works for me at first time click,when i clicked second time the same button ,not working

Comment: nice solution saved my day

Comment: If you use radio group you must remove it . When you removed radio group it will be fix

Answer (score 15):

This is my solution. Its pretty easy.

my_radio_adapter_item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ... />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

MyRadioAdapter.java

```
public class MyRadioAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Variation> mVariations;
    private int mSelectedVariation;


    public MyRadioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Variation> variations, int selectedVariation)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mVariations = variations;
        mSelectedVariation = selectedVariation;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if(view==null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_radio_adapter_item, null);          
        }

        final Variation variation = mVariations.get(position);

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio);

        name.setText(variation.getName());
        if(position==mSelectedVariation) radio.setChecked(true);
        else radio.setChecked(false);

        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                mSelectedVariation = position;
                MyRadioAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: List view is referenced in some fragment or activity and it use just this adapter.

Comment: You did not get the problem. When you will add item to listview then you will not allow to add it into radio group and vice verse.

Comment: I think it's a bit rough and not efficient, but it helped me as a quick solution +1

Comment: Could you pls tell me, what if you have several Radiobuttons horizontal, how to manage then?

Answer (score 2):

You could put a

```
private int selectedIndex = -1;
```

then, in the getView-code you could check

```
if (position == selectedIndex) {
     rbtn.setSelected ( true );
}
else {
     rbtn.setSelected ( false );
}
```

and add a method in your custom adapter:

```
public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
    //some range-checks, maybe
    selectedIndex = index;
    //invalidate
}
```

Then, in your onItemClickedListener you call setSelectedIndex on the position.

Comment: I have try this to. But issue is then getView() call itself multiple times.(To measure width,height).
For me it call multiple times. and if I select 2nd row. Then it show the opposite row(from the bottom in the list) not from top. :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CheckedTextView instead of the normal one.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html

I never used it, but the AlertDialog uses it for the SingleChoice items. So it definitively will work :)

Edit:
don't forget to call

```
 listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: I have check this already. Its fine. But It not give me the above view. But only textview with a checkbox. I am not using this. I need to do this using above view.

Comment: I think it looks better if you have the radio buttons on the right side. And I also would use drawableLeft for the TextView and not an extra ImageView. Is my opinion :)

Comment: @Arslan: Using `CheckedTextView` will work since it implements `Checkable`, you need your custom view to implement that interface.

Comment: Look at the AlertDialog source and the setSingleChoiceItems()

Answer (score 0):

to add to the answers already given, for a more modular approach, have all list items inherit from the same class/interface that have a message function that would allow you to pass massages to them via the adapter.
The adapter registers itself with every item that is added to it, so every list item can call the adapter to send a message.
then, in the RadioButton listener you can send a message to all the other radio buttons to turn off, turn the pressed one on, then finally notify dataset changed on the adapter.

I have an ListAdapter class, and a ListItem abstract class that are fairly robust; I'll send to anyone who needs it.
Multiple list item types supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. Define a variable to get the currently selected position and do the following inside the custom adapter.

```
 singleRadio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            checkedButtonPosition = position;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    if (checkedButtonPosition == position){
        singleRadio.setChecked(true);
    }else {
        singleRadio.setChecked(false);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you need the same output or different...

What i mean is you have select only one of the language from the list. Is it right?

conform it. So that i will give one example for that

Comment: You should comment instead of answer. 
I want to chose one at a time. I know this can be done via some other way. Temporarily I am doing some other way. But this this is what I really need to know that "How to use RadioGroup in ListView custom adapter?"

Comment: then we did not use radio group for the list activity. We will use some properties for the default list like setchoicemode. But using this you did not customize the view

Comment: Yes I know We can use customize list. But this will not look like the above image. I am doing this in some other manner.