# Radio Button Selection.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a `ListView` :

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

The layout of each row of the `ListView` is:

```
<? Xml version="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    > 
    <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/my_img" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_algnParentLeft="true" 
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"          
          /> 
    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/my_value" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_img"
         android:textColor="@drawable/black" /> 
    <RadioButton 
         android:id="@+id/my_radio" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_value" /> 

</ RelativeLayout>
```

As you see above, there is a `RadioButton` on each row of the list, how to implement the following **two features** regards to the `RadioButton`:

**1.** Suppose there are 3 items in the list, how to make the **radio button** on each row perform single selection on the list ? (By default, I can select all of the radio buttons)

**2.** How to have each item row area clickable for the **radio button selection** instead of only click on radio button for selection?

Comment: Maybe help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter

Answer (score 0):

Get a reference to your listView, set its property as

```
lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Also remove the radio button from your xml layout. The above method will automatically put a radio button in each of your list view rows.
Use :

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android: layout_width = "fill_parent" 
    android: layout_height = "fill_parent" 
    > 
    <ImageView 
          android: id = "@+id/my_img" 
          android: layout_width = "wrap_content" 
          android: layout_height = "wrap_content" 
          android:layout_algnParentLeft="true" 
          android: layout_centerVertical = "true"          
          /> 
    <TextView 
         android: id = "@+id/my_value" 
         android: layout_width = "wrap_content" 
         android: layout_height = "wrap_content" 
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_img"
         android: textColor = "@drawable/ black" /> 


</ RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would like when use click on the row area (no matter it is radio button or image icon), the radio button get checked, how to do that?

Comment: After setting choice mode single, on click of row, the radio button for that row will be checked and others unchecked.

Comment: I removed <RadioButton> from my row layout, and added the single choice mode to my list, But there is no Radio button. Can you be more clear, where should the radio button be defined??