# How to make sure that only single radiobutton is selected in childview of expandable list view in android?

Tags: android, radio-button, selection

I am using expandable list view in my app and in its child view,i am using a custom list of radio buttons.The problem here is that i want to make sure that only one radiobutton should be selected at a time.If one radio button is selected,other should be deselected.This is the code i am using:

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition,int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        m_position = childPosition;

        View l_view = convertView;
        if (l_view == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater l_vi = (LayoutInflater)m_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            l_view = l_vi.inflate(R.layout.singleradiobutton, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.l_nameRadioButton = (RadioButton) l_view.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);

            l_view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        EnteringValuesToArrayList l_enteringValuesInstance = m_itemsOfAdapterArrayList.get(childPosition);
        String l_nameOfContact = l_enteringValuesInstance.GetNameOfEntry();

        if (l_nameOfContact != null)
        {
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) l_view.getTag();

            if (holder.l_nameRadioButton != null) 
            {
                holder.l_nameRadioButton.setText(l_nameOfContact);
            }

            if(m_timerValue != 0 && l_enteringValuesInstance.GetTimerValueOfEntry() == m_timerValue)
                holder.l_nameRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            else
                holder.l_nameRadioButton.setChecked(false); 

            holder.l_nameRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(childPosition,holder.l_nameRadioButton.getText(),holder.l_nameRadioButton));          
        }
        return l_view;
    }

    private class OnItemClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {           
        private int l_positionOfItemClicked;
        private CharSequence l_text;
        private RadioButton l_radioButton;
        OnItemClickListener(int position, CharSequence text,RadioButton l_nameRadioButton)
        {
            this.l_positionOfItemClicked = position;
            this.l_text = text;
            this.l_radioButton = l_nameRadioButton;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            l_radioButton.setChecked(true); 
        }
    }
```

I searched a lot,but did not get the solution of the problem.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a RadioGroup http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html

Comment: How to use radio group in custom child view of exapandable list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question is asked in this [How to use RadioGroup in ListView custom adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter)

You can create a custom view in your case.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I checked and tried the solutions but none of them is working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the `radioButtons` in a `RadioGroup`. When grouped together, each `RadioGroup` can have only one button selected at a time. Otherwise, they can all be checked or unchecked.
See the documentation about it [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

Comment: How to use radio group in custom child view of exapandable list view?

Comment: Add the `RadioGroup` to your xml, enclosing the needed `RadioButtons`. Then you can make use of the functions in the documentation as needed

Answer (score 1):

Use RadioGroup instead since RadioGroup "is used to group together one or more RadioButton views, thereby allowing only one RadioButton to be checked within RadioGroup"

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rbtGp1);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbt1);
            if (rb1.isChecked()) {
                // Do something
            else {
                // Do something else
        }
    }
});
```