# ListAdapter not getting view

Tags: android, listadapter

I have `ListAdapter` which fills list with TextView of category and `RadioButton` which is to be checked. So, the problem is that I want user to define which category he wants through List and when he clicks on `RadioButton`, others should be unchecked and so on. I need to set somehow the ID of this RadioButtons and I'm doing that in `getView(...)` method in `ListAdapter` but when it calls for **second time** that method, he doesn't find that `RadioButton` and I get error while trying to set ID of this RadioButton view. I was debugging it, and first time it finds the view through method `findViewById`, but second time it doesn't.

I think I might know the problem for it -> when second time it goes to find the view by ID, it can't find it since I've put already other Identifier on the first call, but how can I set unique identifiers for  my RadioButtons in the list then?

Here is my code:
**getView:**

```
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false);
    }

    ListCategoryItem category = categories.get(index); // categories is list

    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryTitle);
    naziv.setText(kategorija.getNazivKategorije());

    RadioButton radioBtn = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.categoryRadioButton);
    radioBtn.setId(category.getIdCategory());

    return view;
}
```

and here is my layout for category_item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/categoryTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    />

<RadioButton 
    android:id="@+id/categoryRadioButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClick"/>
```

So, how to set unique identifier to my RadioButtons in view properly or can I make somehow group of RadioButtons which will care for itself that when other one is checked, others to be unchecked - something how in HTML is solved up.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter

Comment: Thanks, that helped, also this post:
http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/of-rubber-stamps-and-checkboxes-why-your-listview-is-broken/

Answer (score 0):

By using `setId()`, you are changing the identifier associated with the `RadioButton` that is used to find it in the view tree. You should probably be using `setTag()` instead, which is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28java.lang.Object%29). This method allows you to attach some opaque data object to the view that can be retrieved later using the `getTag()` method.