# Completely Unresponsive Android Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

Can't seem to determine the problem with my adapter.  I am trying to put a progress bar underneath a `checkedTextView` in order to minimize the number of elements and the hassle of a relative layout (putting the loading bar underneath and the radio button to the right side of the `textView`).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
...
    connections = new ArrayList<WifiP2pClient>();//make an arraylist for the connections
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.connectionsListView);//initialize the list view
    adapter = new P2PClientArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_List_item_single_choice, connections);//create an array adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);//attach the adapter to the listView
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
...
}
```

---

```
public class P2PClientArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WifiP2pClient>
{
    private CheckedTextView checkedTextView;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    int lastRadioButtonPressed;
    CheckedTextView lastPressedTextView;
    public P2PClientArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<WifiP2pClient> clients)
    {
        super(context, resource, clients);
        lastRadioButtonPressed = -1;
        lastPressedTextView = null;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        WifiP2pClient client = getItem(position);
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

            checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.clientToString);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.clientProgressBar);

            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    if(position != lastRadioButtonPressed)
                    {
                        if(lastPressedTextView != null)
                        {
                            lastPressedTextView.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        lastRadioButtonPressed = position;
                        lastPressedTextView = checkedTextView;
                        checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
                        P2PClientArrayAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        checkedTextView.setText(client.toString());
        progressBar.setProgress(client.getProgress());
        return row;
    }
}
```

Currently, the issue is that the adapter is non-responsive.  I update the `WifiP2pClient` with an asynchronous task and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` quite often, but the data displayed in the UI never updates.  In addition, when I press the `listView`, nothing happens (not even the normal black depress animation).

If I instead use a regular `ArrayListAdapter<String>` object, the `arrayList` updates properly, so I know that the rest of the code works properly, it's something wrong with this `arrayAdapter`.

EDIT: I'm putting the `onClickListener()` in the `getView()` based on this post:
[How to use RadioGroup in ListView custom adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter)

EDIT2: I got the adapter to properly respond to the changes made to it AND the press by the user by ensuring that the `checkedViewText` and `progressBar` objects were properly updated when the view was not null by using a `ViewHolder` object and the view's `setTag()` and `getTag()` functionality.  I will be pasting this code in shortly.  I still don't have the adapter returning proper values for `getCheckedItemPosition()`, however.

Comment: why are you putting the onclicklistener inside the getView() of the adapter? It should be on the adapter itself.

Comment: Maybe you could post the code where you are updating the adapter with the new data?

Answer (score 0):

After doing enough experimenting and getting a lucky break, here is my finished code (for future googlers and comparison's sake).

```
public class P2PClientArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WifiP2pClient>
{
    //The viewholder object isn't neccessary but it allows us to Tag.set()
    //with no indicies because we have it wrapped in one big object
    private class ViewHolder
    {
        CheckedTextView checkedTextView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
    }

    int lastRadioButtonPressed;
    CheckedTextView lastPressedTextView;

    public P2PClientArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<WifiP2pClient> clients)
    {
        super(context, resource, clients);
        lastRadioButtonPressed = -1;
        lastPressedTextView = null;
    }

    //I wasn't sure how to override ListView's getCheckedItemPosition()
    //So I made my own and then changed the calling code.
    public int getCheckedItemPosition()
    {
        return lastRadioButtonPressed;
    }
    //If you delete an element in your list, you have 
    //to reset the pointer or you'll have logic errors.
    public void resetCheckedItemPosition()
    {
        lastRadioButtonPressed = -1;
        lastPressedTextView = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        WifiP2pClient client = getItem(position);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView)row.findViewById(R.id.clientToString);
            viewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.clientProgressBar);

            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(position != lastRadioButtonPressed)
                {
                    if(lastPressedTextView != null)
                    {
                        lastPressedTextView.setChecked(false);
                    }
                    lastRadioButtonPressed = position;
                    lastPressedTextView = viewHolder.checkedTextView;
                    viewHolder.checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });
        viewHolder.checkedTextView.setText(client.toString());
        viewHolder.progressBar.setProgress(client.getProgress());
        return row;
    }
}
```