# Android Listview of radio button with image

Tags: android, listview

Is it possible to create such listview in Android. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrVGS.png)

I know it's possible to do it as flat list with small images. For example, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use RecyclerView and CardView, [here](https://github.com/David-Hackro/ExamplesAndroid/tree/master/RecyclerViewAndCardView) a example :D

It's a option.

[image]